# Sequelize Model is not associated to Post

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to fix the issue but nothing! This is a simple relation like User has many posts and like below is my models, I am in hurry to deliver this project and my deadline is too near. Would you please look into this?

```
// user.js
import { Model, DataTypes } from "sequelize";
import connection from "../connection";

const initUser = (sequelize, Types) => {
    class User extends Model {
        /**
         * Helper method for defining associations.
         * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
         * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
         */
        static associate(models) {
            // define association here
        }
    }
    User.init(
        {
            id: {
                type: Types.UUID,
                defaultValue: Types.UUIDV4,
                primaryKey: true,
            },
            first_name: Types.STRING,
            last_name: Types.STRING,
            email: Types.STRING,
            password: Types.STRING,
        },
        {
            sequelize,
            modelName: "User",
            tableName: "users",
            createdAt: "created_at",
            updatedAt: "updated_at",
        }
    );
    User.associate = function (models) {
        User.hasMany(models.Post, { foreignKey: "userId", as: "posts" });
    };
    return User;
};

export default initUser(connection, DataTypes);
```

And the post model

```
// post.js
import { Model, DataTypes } from "sequelize";
import connection from "../connection";

const initPost = (sequelize, Types) => {
    class Post extends Model {
        /**
         * Helper method for defining associations.
         * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
         * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
         */
        static associate(models) {
            // define association here
        }
    }
    Post.init(
        {
            id: {
                type: Types.UUID,
                defaultValue: Types.UUIDV4,
                primaryKey: true,
            },
            title: DataTypes.STRING,
            slug: DataTypes.STRING,
            overview: DataTypes.TEXT,
            userId: {
                type: DataTypes.UUID,
                allowNull: false,
                onDelete: "CASCADE",
                references: {
                    model: "users",
                    key: "id",
                    as: "userId",
                },
            },
        },
        {
            sequelize,
            modelName: "Post",
            tableName: "posts",
            createdAt: "created_at",
            updatedAt: "updated_at",
        }
    );
    Post.associate = function (models) {
        Course.belongsTo(models.Post, { foreignKey: "userId", as: "posts" });
    };
    return Post;
};
export default initPost(connection, DataTypes);
```

And here is my query below

```
const posts = await Post.findAll({
    order: [["created_at", "DESC"]],
    include: [
        {
            model: User,
            as: "user",
        },
    ],
    where: { userId: userId },
});
```

But it's showing me an error like

> "User is not associated to Post!"

What is wrong I can't figure out.

Thanks

Comment: would you please share your index file?

Comment: @fool-dev Here is no index file, would you please suggest it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a file called `index.js` into the `models` folder like below

```
import User from "./user";
import Post from "./post";

User.hasMany(Post, { foreignKey: "userId", as: "posts" });
Post.belongsTo(User, { foreignKey: "userId", as: "user" });


export { User, Post };
```

And in the API like below

```
import { Post, User } from "db/models";

const posts = await Post.findAll({
    order: [["created_at", "DESC"]],
    include: [
        {
            model: User,
            as: "user",
        },
    ],
    where: { userId: userId },
});
```

Hope it will help.